# Use local copy of python package rather than the one installed in site-packages

Tags: python

I've installed a Python based package in my site-packages directory. However, I'm trying to learn how the code works so I'd like to hack it a bunch by putting in lots of print statements so I can understand what the code is doing. But at the end of the day I want a clean installation without all my hacks in it.

Of course I could just copy the original files to something else, make some hacks, and then at the end copy all the original files back over. But that's really tedious. At the very least, I'd like to install a local copy of the Python package and then have the python script use this copy preferentially (perhaps by suitable statements at the top of the script). But perhaps this isn't even the best way to do python development/hacking.

What's the best solution for my problem? I want to be able to hack on the package (and use that package) but without messing up my clean version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtualenv-advice given is correct, depending on your actual package you can even go beyond that and not mess with the site-packages inside the virtualenv at all.

If the package is setuptools-based, a simple

```
$ python setup.py develop
```

from within a working-copy of it's source, it won't be installed, but instead just hooked into the virtualenv pointing to the working-copy. Advantage: you can edit (and e.g. rollback using GIT or whatever SCM the package maintainer uses) files in a well-defined and non-volatile location.

Comment: Actually, this IS how my package was installed, per their instructions. I just noticed that my package isn't actually in site-packages, but there is a file there called [mypackage].egg-link, which lists my local installation directory to the directory in site-packages.  So I suppose this is how it's working? And I can presumably just use git checkout to revert my changes back to the actual distribution?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I switched your response to the answer since it was most helpful to me personally (as per the stackexchange [guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You can basically setup a local python environment in which you can install anything you like without having to mess around with the system environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the Python [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tool is for.  It allows you to create a local Python environment with a set of packages distinct from your system installation.  For example, I could do something like this:

```
$ virtualenv myenv
$ . myenv/bin/activate
$ pip install nifty-module
```

The `activate` script modifies your `PATH` so that any script that starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

will use the Python from your virtual environment, rather than the system Python, and will see the modules installed in that environment.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. While @deets answer actually works easiest for me (because I didn't realize what `setup.py develop` did), this answer seems to be the most general and virtualenv looks like a very useful package for future work.